# AFNetworking error - AFHTTPRequestOperationManager (symbols not found for architecture x86_64)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, afnetworking-2

I am implementing AFNetworking in my applicatioin.

I import folder AFNetworking and UIKit+AFNetworking successfully in my application. My code is as below.

```
#import "AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
    [manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

The above code is not actual code but to just check whether everything is working properly or not but here I got the error:

> symbols not found for architecture x86_64

I refer several links of Stack Overflow but I am not able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, 
The problem was Other linking flags field of target

```
[!] The `SPEEPHOTAG [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `SPEEPHOTAG [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

when i write the `$(inherited)` to other linking flags, it added required flags for `AFNetworking` and the problem is solved for me.